# "False" is being inserted to column instead of stated value when using fillna in pandas, python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to fill in values in one column with a specific value based on what value is in another column. E.g I want small to have one value in and medium nulls to have another value.

```
| Size | Number |
|:-----|:-------|
|Small | 34 |
|Small |  |
|Medium| 45|
|Large| 72|
|Medium|  |
|Small|  |
|Large| 89|
|Small| 45|
|Medium| 32|
|Medium|  |
```

I'm using

```
df['Number'].fillna(df.groupby(df['Size']=='Small') == 10, inplace = True)
```

but this resulting in:

```
| Size | Number |
|:-----|:-------|
|Small | 34 |
|Small | FALSE |
|Medium| 45|
|Large| 72|
|Medium|  |
|Small|  FALSE|
|Large| 89|
|Small| 45|
|Medium| 32|
|Medium|  |
```

I'm expecting '10' to be added where False has been put.
I've been stuck on this for ages. Can anyone tell me why it isn't inserting the value? Its finding the right rows to fill in but just not adding the value I want.

Please note that I'm working with a much larger database loaded from file and this is just an example df for my issue. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe use `=` instead of `==` in your code? Not quite sure if this will work, but here is what I mean: `df['Number'].fillna(df.groupby(df['Size]=='Small') = 10, inplace = True)`.

Comment: please provide the explicit expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that empty values, are not necessarily considered as Nulls, and therefore fillna will fail. Also, because of the evaluation you are making, you are creating a boolean pd.Series which is being passed as argument to the fillna() function, and not the strict value `10` which I assumed you intend to use. I would go with `np.where()`:

```
df['Number'] = np.where((df['Number'].isna()) & (df['Size'] == 'Small'),10,
                        np.where((df['Number'].isna()) & (df['Size']=='Medium'),50,
                                 df['Number']))
```

This will return specific values (10 and 50) when the conditions are met, otherwise return the original number.

Returning:

```
0   Small    34.0
1   Small    10.0
2  Medium    45.0
3   Large    72.0
4  Medium    50.0
5   Small    10.0
6   Large    89.0
7   Small    45.0
8  Medium    32.0
9  Medium    50.0
```

Comment: This worked!! I'd tried np.where and it had complained about me using float points but apparently I hadn't got all my brackets in the right place and used an 'equal' when I shouldn't have. I obviously still have so much to learn when it comes to python. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Happy to know it worked, thank you for accepting the answer! Chaining functions is very interesting, if there's any follow up questions feel free to let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can try `fillna` on selected rows

```py
mask = df['Size'].eq('Small')
df.loc[mask, 'Number'] = df.loc[mask, 'Number'].fillna(10)
```

```
print(df)

     Size  Number
0   Small    34.0
1   Small    10.0
2  Medium    45.0
3   Large    72.0
4  Medium     NaN
5   Small    10.0
6   Large    89.0
7   Small    45.0
8  Medium    32.0
9  Medium     NaN
```